# TYPO3: Hide tt_news completely if there is no news to show and replace by content element

Tags: hide, typo3, tt-news

I'm looking for a way to hide the tt_news extension when there is no news or only archived newsartikles for a category, and then show a fixed content element in its place.
I don't even know if it's possible but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would need tt_news to check for available articles anyway, but you could extend it to show a content element in the case of no current news. The best starting point would probably be the place where tt_news displays the "no news to display" message. Perhaps there's a hook, else you'll have to XCLASS.

Or, to put it another way: Of course it's possible, but to the best of my knowledge not without extending tt_news.